# Rails 3, ActiveRecord, Detecting changes in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::base 
  has_many :memberships
end
```

What I would like to do is to detect in the `users_controller` update action that some memberships have been added or removed from the `user.memberships`.

Any idea or suggestion on how to implement this?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: My apologies if the question was not clear.

Users are linked together by a parent-child relationship. This relationship is implemented through memberships to a Family circle.

What I want is that when a child user joins a Classroom circle automagically the parent of the child also joins the same Classroom circle. In other words adding/removing memberships to a child user needs to be propagated to his parents users.

Comment: We're going to need more context than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies if the context was not very clear. 
So first some context clarification:

Users are linked together by a parent-child relationship. This relationship is implemented through memberships to a Family circle.

What I want is that when a child user joins a Classroom circle automagically the parent of the child also joins the same Classroom circle. In other words adding/removing memberships to a child user needs to be propagated to his parents users.

**Now the solution:**
The way I have solved this is by adding the after_save and before_destroy methods to the Membership model to check is the user is a child and in that case to create/destroy membership for the parents. There are several tricky edge-cases I had to solve but the code seems to be working fine.

A final note: my first idea was to somehow detect in the user controller that memberships  have been added or removed and then check if the user was a child user....

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party here, but for future travelers [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+callbacks) exposes `before_add`, `after_add`, `before_remove`, and `after_remove` hooks for exactly these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Added how? Since the last visit?

If so, then make a "read" boolean column that updates when you visit.

Otherwise, elaborate. :)

Comment: Added means inserted. So adding a boolean will not work unless I do maintain it for each user (reader). But thanks for the reply.